# How to install Parse CloudCode in windows7 32bit?

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, cygwin, parse-cloud-code

we are developing android app using parse `CloudCode`,we unable install `CloudCode` setup in windows7 32bit using Cygwin terminal getting error at installer.sh command line[image: we are new to this particular technology]

Please guide us,where we are doing mistake..!
[We followed this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_A6Y9i7b28) In this video its working properely &
[we followed these screenshots installation from here](https://chrispogeek.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/setting-up-parse-cloud-code-tool-in-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change the DOS EOL (the \r) of `installer.sh` to Unix EOL using `dos2unix` command  or notepad++ (Edit -> EOL conversion -> Unix format).
And it seems you do not have curl installed.